# Do I need to store an access token for security purposes when creating an android app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an android app which uses facebook to login.  I am then storing all user data in a database on my server. Should I store the users access token also or would it be secure enough to just use the userid in the database and let only the app handle if the user is valid or not? For example. If I have a database that stores a list that I only want that user to see and I am using FB to authenticate. would it be secure enough not to have to verify the fb access token every time they access their list?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this doesn't account for the situation where user may have revoked access to your app or if user has changed his password. You will need to always look out for the invalid access_token and redirect user to re-authorize your app. For invalid access token, following error :

```
User revoked access to your app:
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token: User               
 1053947411 has not authorized application 157111564357680."}}

OR when password changed:
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token: 
The session is invalid because the user logged out."}}
```

Comment: But would it be necessary to store the access token in the database where the userid is stored or would it be secure enough to just store the user id?

Comment: You should store your Access token either in DB as you like or simply in Preferences.. Every time you should check for Valid Token , if Valid then only you should allow user to your App